# Can't create an xpath capable of meeting certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

I've created a script which is able to extract the links ending with `.html` extention available under class `tableFile` from a webpage. The script can do it's job. However, my intention at this point is to get only those `.html` links which have `EX-` in its type field. I'm looking for any pure xpath solution (by not using `.getparent()` or something).

[Link to that site](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/0001469709-18-000185-index.htm)

Script I've tried with so far:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/0001469709-18-000185-index.htm")
root = fromstring(res.text)

for item in root.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href'):
    if ".htm" in item:
        print(item)
```

When I try to get the links meeting above condition with the below approach, I get an error:

```
for item in root.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href'):
    if ".htm" in item and "EX" in item.xpath("..//following-sibling::td/text"):
        print(item)
```

Error I get:

```
if ".htm" in item and "EX" in item.xpath("..//following-sibling::td/text"):
AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

This is how the files look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need pure XPath solution, you can use below:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

res = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/0001469709-18-000185-index.htm")
root = fromstring(res.text)
for item in root.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//tr[td[starts-with(., "EX-")]]/td/a[contains(@href, ".htm")]/@href'):
    print(item)


/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/ex31_1apg.htm
/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/ex31_2apg.htm
/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/ex32_1apg.htm
/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/ex32_2apg.htm
```

Comment: Apology for the delayed response @sir Andersson. Thanks for your effective solution.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same using `.cssselect()` @sir Andersson? I hope you will take a look in your spare time.

Comment: @robots.txt , you can try `[link.attrib['href'] for link in root.cssselect('table[summary*="Document"] td>a:contains("ex")[href*="htm"]')]` , but CSS selectors are not so flexible IMHO, so it's not the same as provided XPath

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using dataframes and pandas

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/0001469709-18-000185-index.htm")
base = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1085596/000146970918000185/"
results = [base + row[1][2] for row in tables[0].iterrows() if row[1][2].endswith(('.htm', '.txt')) and str(row[1][3]).startswith('EX')]
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
//td[following-sibling::td[starts-with(text(), "EX")]]/a[contains(@href, ".htm")]
```

There's a lot of different ways to do this with xpath. Css is probalby much simpler.